# How do I start Gnome Deskop with a new session at login

Tags: gnome, login, 20.04, session

I was tinkering with Ubuntu 20.04 and Htop. I think, in error I have killed a process. Now after a reboot and login the mouse pointer is disabled. It is fine up to logging in and with other users.

I am assuming this disabled pointer is saved in the current session. In other Linuxes there is an option to set the session as Saved, Current or New. Is this possible in Ubuntu 20.04 or is it possible to go back to a default session? There has to be a easier way other than reinstall.

Comment: Hi, now the problem is are you not able to use the session bcoz of the invisible mouse? to get away with this you need to choose new session?